# When learning new languages related readings, Distractions or Aids?

Tags: c++, programming-languages

When learning new languages such as C++ from PHP, does reading other language snippets help you understand better by giving one a different prospective, or does doing so confuse a noob like me? Also, any advice on learning C++ would be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I find that reading short snippets helps a lot. A good book is really handy too. Once you understand most of the language itself, reading large, full-size programs helps a lot with learning how common problems are solved in that language. Most languages don't have a term for this, but it is like the "Pythonic" way in Python.

As for learning C++, first get a good understanding of C. C is quite simple, so it shouldn't take that long. Once you know C, start learning about the C++ specific features one at a time. This way, you can still write useful programs (C is mostly a subset of C++), before you learn the real "C++ic" way.

Comment: Do I mod this up? I agree with the 'learn C first', but do I stump my answer ... decisions decisions :) We can exchange :P

Comment: Zifre, don't know if you upped, but I will now :P

Answer (score 2):

I find it helps to

1. Get a good grasp of the syntax and semantics of the language, by looking at SIMPLE examples and relating it to something **you already know**
2. Look at what libraries and design patterns are common. Find out **why** they are common. Was the language designed to encourage them? Is it convention? Efficient?
3. **have an idea** that you want to implement in the language. It will give you a goal, and some perspective.
4. Look at other's code, once you are comfortable picking apart and reading it, and comfortable with source-layout, conventions, common-naming and so on

I find it best to dive-in heads first. Get feedback from people if possible. Most importantly:

**don't be afraid of making mistakes** they are a big part of the learning process. And try and **relate things** to concepts you are already comfortable with.

Answer (score 1):

If you are sufficiently inexperienced to ask this question, I recommend that you read short snippets, but *not* in another language.  A better mental exercise is to say given a short snippet in the new language (C++), how would it compare with what you would *write* in the old language you already know (PHP)?  Similarly, if you read about a new C++ thing, ask what PHP snippets you could express in the new C++ish way.

Regarding C++ itself, there are plenty of other SO questions to trawl.  I think it bears repeating that the *Design Patterns* book with four authors is very helpful to learn the vocabulary and mindset of many longtime C++ programmers.